# Calculate Sum of Random observations as sum per week in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, group-by, sum

I have a dataset of random, sometimes infrequent, events that I want to count as a sum per week. Due to the randomness they are not linear so other examples I have tried so far are not applicable.

The data is similar to this:

```
df_date <- data.frame( Name = c("Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim","Jim",
                                "Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue","Sue"),
                       Dates = c("2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                                 "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28",
                                 "2010-1-1", "2010-1-2", "2010-01-5","2010-01-17","2010-01-20",
                                 "2010-01-29","2010-02-6","2010-02-9","2010-02-16","2010-02-28"),
                       Event = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) )
```

What I'm trying to do is create a new table that contains the sum of events per week in the calendar year.

In this case producing something like this:

```
Name   Week   Events
Jim    1      3
Sue    1      3
Jim    2      0
Sue    x ...  x 

and so on...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that gets you each ISO week for each individual, with zeros when there are no events for that week for that individual:

```
get_dates_df <- function(d) {
  data.frame(date = seq(min(d, na.rm=T),max(d,na.rm=T),1)) %>% 
    mutate(Year=year(date), Week=week(date)) %>% 
    distinct(Year, Week)    
}

df_date = df_date %>% mutate(Dates=lubridate::ymd(Dates))

left_join(
  full_join(distinct(df_date %>% select(Name)), get_dates_df(df_date$Dates), by=character()),
  df_date %>% 
  group_by(Name,Year=year(Dates), Week=week(Dates)) %>% 
  summarize(Events = sum(Event), .groups="drop")
) %>% 
  mutate(Events=if_else(is.na(Events),0,Events))
```

Output:

```
   Name Year Week Events
1   Jim 2010    1      3
2   Jim 2010    2      0
3   Jim 2010    3      2
4   Jim 2010    4      0
5   Jim 2010    5      1
6   Jim 2010    6      2
7   Jim 2010    7      1
8   Jim 2010    8      0
9   Jim 2010    9      1
10  Sue 2010    1      3
11  Sue 2010    2      0
12  Sue 2010    3      2
13  Sue 2010    4      0
14  Sue 2010    5      1
15  Sue 2010    6      2
16  Sue 2010    7      1
17  Sue 2010    8      0
18  Sue 2010    9      1
```

Comment: This looks perfect as it addresses the problem I just realized I have in my dates traversing more that 1 year in my real dataset. Though when i try to run it, even on the example, I get this error ```Error in seq.default(min(d), max(d), 1) : 'from' must be a finite number```

Comment: you might have NA in your dates?.., or you didnt' convert the Dates column from character to Date (as in both solutions)... see my edit

Answer (score 5):

**Update OP request for multiple years:**

We could use `isoweek` also from `lubridate` instead of `week`

**OR:**

We could add the year as follows:

```
df_date %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Week = week(ymd(Dates))) %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(ymd(Dates))) %>% 
  count(Name, Year, Week)
```

We could use `lubridate`s `Week` function after transforming character `Dates` to date format with `lubridate`s `ymd` function.
Then we can use `count` which is the short for   `group_by(Name, Week) %>% summarise(Count = n())`
:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df_date %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(Week = week(ymd(Dates))) %>% 
  count(Name, Week)
```

```
  Name   Week     n
   <chr> <dbl> <int>
 1 Jim       1     3
 2 Jim       3     2
 3 Jim       5     1
 4 Jim       6     2
 5 Jim       7     1
 6 Jim       9     1
 7 Sue       1     3
 8 Sue       3     2
 9 Sue       5     1
10 Sue       6     2
11 Sue       7     1
12 Sue       9     1
```

Comment: This is great @TarJae! And answers the question I posted perfectly. Though I realized when I went back to my actual dataset that it traverses more than 1 year. Is it possible to amend to allow for that. Maybe add a column with the year?

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: Thanks very much for addressing my request @TarJae! This works perfectly also. I do have one more item if you have time. Currently it does not include the weeks with counts of 0. Is it possible to amend the code to do so? I'd like to chart the data as a time series to demonstrate the change in frequency of events.